# How do I vent a new above-range vent on an interior wall into the previous, existing island downdraft vent which outlets 36’ away

Tags: hvac, vent, range, hood

How can I tie in a new range hood, interior wall (with 2nd floor) to the previous down draft island vent (1986). The vent would go 13’ then into a crawl space under a sunroom and will exit at a total of 27’ on the other side of the room. Code is 30’ I’m told, and each elbow subtracts 5 of those feet.  Help!  I’m spending $60,000 on a new kitchen and I don’t want my house to stink!  TYIA

Comment: How many elbows will you have? Sounds like at least one so far, and 27 + 5 = 32 > 30, so maybe already too long?

Comment: If you're already spending $60k, spend another $1 or 2k to have new duct work installed? Just run it straight up the interior wall, through the 2nd floor and straight out the roof...

Comment: Can you re-route or put in a new shorter duct/vent?

Comment: just add a booster fan

Comment: Add a drawing of the space with dimensions. Include the direction that your ceiling joists run. If there are no girders blocking the ceiling joist cavities, then you should be able to go through a joist cavity and the rim board to reach the outside.

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Yes!  I need to route it the opposite direction under the basement floor joists which is accessible, and only 14’ to the outside wall!  The one issue is the center 'carrying beam' of the house runs  right through the joists there.  Can’t cut through it to make the duct run.  I’m hoping can go above or below.  I’m ok with weird or ugly in the basement as long as it passes code.  Any ideas about this obstruction?  TY!  All!

Comment: _Under_ the floor joists? Are you running this new route below drywall and parallel to joists? Your "_above_ or below" statement make me think that your duct runs below drywall and then butts into the carrying beam. In that scenario the joists are bearing on top of the bearing beam. If this is the case, then why not run the duct between joists the whole way?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is for you to go into the wall behind your new OTR vent, then down inside the wall, across under the floor to your old downdraft duct.  Personally, I think it'd be easier to go *up* into the ceiling and across to the side of the house.

Comment: Again, TY everyone.  I got an hvac person to come out.  Using the old duct is out, as Triplefault said, But yes the duct can run down the wall behind , & across the floor the opposite direction under the den, 14’, and out the front wall!  I need a remote fan in the basement, and then a hood only.  My contractor is mad , he’s telling me 'fine, let me know when it’s done and I’ll maybe start working on the kitchen again'.  Yes, he’s angry I didn’t just shut up, listen to him and get the circulating fan - not bother him.  This was supposed to be part of the job, now I’m supposed to pay for it!